# Visual Studio 2010 Web Test Detecting Dynamic Parameters Never Stops

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

I am using VS 2010 Ultimate with SP1.

I am unable to create a web test going to www.google.com. The "Detecting dynamic parameters..." dialog never stops. I have tried to turn this feature off. But when I do, I am unable to get past the first request when trying to execute the recorded web test. Also, when trying to "Promote Dynamic Parameters," it never completes either.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing VS 2010 Ultimate SP1. I had the same problem and I re-installed VS with SP1 and my recorded web test was able to run properly again.

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=23691)